# How to suppress warnings from Generate DSYMFile?

Tags: xcode

I'm getting millions of these warnings in Xcode 12.5

```
warning: could not find referenced DIE
```

How can I suppress those warnings?

Better yet, does anyone know what these warnings are and how to correct them? Just started getting them since Xcode 12.x.

Thanks.